# how to read multiple values from a field in csv file using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, multiple-value

Hi I have a csv file delimited by comma like this.

```
name, email1; Email2; email3, etc, telephone
```

I want to extract all the emails addresses from the email field using csv module in python. And from each email address write a row using the other fields  like this

```
name, email1, etc, telephone
name, Email2, etc, telephone
name, email3, etc, telephone
```

Maybe I need to read the email field and split it in separated strings?

Comment: Yes maybe you do. Implement it and then ask a question if you run into a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CSV reader and writer, and as you said, read the file using the standard `,` separator, and then split the email field manually using `;`. For each email entry, write the other fields:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        emails = row[1].split(';')
        for email in emails:
            csv_output.writerow([row[0], email]  + row[3:])
```

Or slightly more compact as:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        csv_output.writerows([row[0], email] + row[3:] for email in row[1].split(';'))
```

Tested using Python 3.x